# Using random.nextBoolean() - random generator

Tags: java

In the example below the while loops simulates a mechanic seeing 10 used engines. Each engine has a 50% chance of working or not working. My variable counter keeps tracks of the number of working engines and prints it out at the end of the program.

My question is this the correct and best possible way to use the rgen.nextBoolean()? Is it better to put rgen.nextBoolean in method and then call that method from inside the while loop?  Also, I'm a little confused how if(rgen.nextBoolean()) knows it's evaluating n if you don't specifically tell the rgen.nextBoolean() in the if condition that you're giving it n as a value?

```
import acm.program.*;
import acm.util.*;

public class WorkingEngines extends ConsoleProgram{
public void run(){


int n = 0;
int counter = 0;

    while (n < 10) {
     if (rgen.nextBoolean()){
       counter++;
          }  
      n++;
      }
 println("out of ten random engines you have" + counter + " working properly");
 }




private RandomGenerator rgen = RandomGenerator.getInstance();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Also, I'm a little confused how if(rgen.nextBoolean()) knows it's evaluating n if you don't specifically tell the rgen.nextBoolean() in the if condition that you're giving it n as a value?

It isn't. It couldn't possibly know. So, what IS going on?

A random number generator has an internal state. The internal state sits until you ask it for a new random number, whereupon the state is pseudo-randomly changed and a new random value corresponding to the new state is returned. So if you generate three random number generators with three starting states and ask them for booleans they will return different sequences of booleans, but if you generate them all with the same starting state (such as by passing a seed of 0 to all of them when constructed) they will all produce the same sequence, for forever.

Other thoughts:

Why use a while n < 10, ++n loop when this is better expressed in terms of a for loop?

What's the difference between calling nextBoolean and calling nextBoolean in a method, unless you plan to make the method subclassed and overridable, for example?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is this the correct and best possible way to use the
>   rgen.nextBoolean()?

The general contract of nextBoolean is that one boolean value is pseudorandomly generated and returned. The values true and false are produced with (approximately) equal probability.

> Is it better to put rgen.nextBoolean in method and then call that
>   method from inside the while loop?

Better respect from what, it's more correct to put in a method but if it only has 2 lines has no sense. what you can do is `while(n++ < 10)`

> Also, I'm a little confused how if(rgen.nextBoolean()) knows it's
>   evaluating n if you don't specifically tell the rgen.nextBoolean() in
>   the if condition that you're giving it n as a value?

You are not giving n, you can use this another method,
nextBoolean(double p)

> public boolean nextBoolean(double p) Returns a random boolean value
>   with the specified probability. You can use this method to simulate an
>   event that occurs with a particular probability. For example, you
>   could simulate the result of tossing a coin like this:    String
>   coinFlip = rgen.nextBoolean(0.5) ? "HEADS" : "TAILS";
>
> Parameters: p - A value between 0 (impossible) and 1 (certain)
>   indicating the probability Returns: The value true with probability p

Comment: about what? may i don't understand you, hope it was useful

Answer (score 1):

You are not specifying the probability when you call rgen.nextBoolean().

You need to change the line:

```
 if (rgen.nextBoolean()){
```

to:

```
 if (rgen.nextBoolean(0.5)){//The "0.5" in the brackets will set the probability to 50%
```

If that does not work I would try :

```
public void run(){


int n = 0;
int counter = 0;
int coinToss;

while (n < 10) {
 coinToss = rgen.nextBoolean( 0.5 );
 if (rgen.nextBoolean()){
   counter++;
      }  
  n++;
  }
 println("out of ten random engines you have" + counter + " working properly");
 }
```

Best of luck!

Also, please consult the documentation on [RandomGenerator](http://jtf.acm.org/javadoc/student/acm/util/RandomGenerator.html#nextBoolean%28double%29) .